# Trigger breakpoint when string is not a Google-owned domain

Tags: vb.net

Basically, I want the code to break when `strLink` doesn't contain any domains in the `googleDomains` link.

The code seems to be very awkward. I wonder if there is a way to make this more elegant.

```
Dim googleDomains = {"google.com", "blogger.com", "youtube.com"}
Dim pass = False
For Each domaingoogle In googleDomains
    If strLink.Contains(domaingoogle) Then
        pass = True
    End If
Next
If Not pass Then
    Dim hello2 = 1 'set breakpoint here.
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you could look at is [Regex](https://regex101.com/). If you're willing to assume that `strLink` is in fact a valid URL you could try something like

```
Dim googleDomains = {"google.com", "blogger.com", "youtube.com"}
Dim regexp = "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+\.com)"
Dim match = Regex.Match(strLink, regexp)
If match.Length <> 0 Then
    Dim domain As String = match.Groups(1).Value
    If Not googleDomains.Contains(domain) Then
        Dim hello2 = 1 'set breakpoint here.
    End If
End If
```

If you wanted to expand to include ".org" or ".net" you could do something like this:

```
Dim regexp = "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n]+\.(com|org|net|gov))"
```

Modified Example [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bG8yB4/1)

In general, I'd say Regex is a very useful tool to have in your arsenal and would be good to learn. Comes in handy when you need to scan large code files or restructure something in a lot of places (as Regex can do replacements as well)

In this example the main benefit is that you can actually extract out the domain from a well-formed URL rather than just see if "google.com" is anywhere in the string

---

If you want the actual check to truly be `String.Contains` You could do something with LINQ

```
Dim domain = googleDomains.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) strLink.Contains(d))
If domain = Nothing Then
    Dim hello2 = 1 'set breakpoint here.
End If
```

A little bit less verbose, but it doesn't necessarily mean the string is a valid URL to google.com

Comment: not more elegant. more complicated. But yea +1

Comment: @JimThio One day it won't seem so complicated :)